# How to send mail from a remote SMTP host?

Tags: email, authentication, smtp, postfix

I have Postfix suite installed locally on Ubuntu 10.10.  I can send/receive mail to my local address, e.g. `user@local.com`.  I'm given credentials to a remote mail server mailbox, e.g. `other@remote.com`.

What command line incantation on my local box would connect me to SMTP server at `remote.com` providing username and password and send mail through it?

I've read `sendmail` and `smtp` manpages but that didn't give me any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Postfix turned out to be irrelevant to my problem.  Using it would be an overkill for this task: it requires per-host configuration, where per-user would do.

I figured out `msmtp` is well enough for my task.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have Postfix relay the messages to the remote server.  This will require a change to the Postfix configuration. You'll need to enable [Postfix's SASL authentication](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_enable) to handle the authentication.  Once configured, you can use your local SMTP server as you did with local addresses, and the local server will relay them on the the remote server.